# Customize material UI Switch when checked and disabled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm having trouble adding the styling to a Material UI Switch in React when it is disabled. I'd like to use withStyles for this. The handling for the checked vs unchecked states works fine as does the styling for the track, but nothing I've tried has worked to style the disabled state of either the thumb or the track.

Here's the code I'm using including some commented out attempts to style the disabled state:

```
const MySwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
        color: "orange",
        opacity: 0.8,
        "&$checked": {
            color: "orange",
            opacity: 1
        },
        "&$checked + $track": {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 1
        },
        // "&$checked + $disabled": {
        //     color: "gray",
        //     opacity: 1
        // },
        // "&disabled": {
        //     color: "gray",
        //     opacity: 1
        // },
        // "&:disabled": {
        //     color: "gray",
        //     opacity: 1
        // },
    },
    // disabled: {
    //     "& + $thumb": {
    //         color: "gray"
    //     }
    // },
    checked: {},
    track: {}
})(Switch);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ryan and Giovanni. Both of your answers contributed to my figuring it out. Key thing from Ryan is that in order to use "&$disabled" in a rule, we need to have "disabled:{}" in there too. And then Giovanni's answer got me thinking about how the disabled states and checked states interact. Here was my code that got disabled to work and was able to style something that was both checked and disabled which was my ultimate goal:

```
const MySwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
        // thumb when unchecked
        color: "orange",
        opacity: 0.8,
        "&$checked": {
            // thumb when checked
            color: "orange",
            opacity: 1,
            // track when checked
            "& + $track": {
                backgroundColor: "black",
                opacity: 1,
            },
            // The rules above override the default rules for graying 
            // out the thumb and track when the switch is disabled,
            // so we have to add that back in ourselves
            "&$disabled": {
                // gray out the thumb
                color: "#bbb",
                "& + $track": {
                    // gray out the track
                    backgroundColor: "#ddd"
                }
            }
        },
    },
    checked: {},
    track: {},
    disabled: {}
})(Switch);
```

Comment: Happy to ear that. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 4):

When having difficulty customizing the styles for a particular component, there are two main resources to look at:

1. The customization examples in the documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/switches/#customized-switches
2. The default styles in the source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.12.2/packages/material-ui/src/Switch/Switch.js#L93

The main issue I see with your commented-out attempts are that you didn't use the correct syntax for referring to the disabled state. Within `switchBase`, you can either use `"&$disabled"` (which requires that you separately include `disabled: {}` since `$` is used to [refer to other style rules](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.7.1#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet) declared within the same `withStyles` call) or `"&.Mui-disabled"` (leveraging the [global class name](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes) that `$disabled` will resolve to).
Below is an example of the correct syntax modeled off of the approach used for the default disabled styles (using colors that make it obvious that the customization is working):

```
import React from "react";
import MuiSwitch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Switch = withStyles({
  switchBase: {
    "&$disabled": {
      color: "yellow"
    },
    "&$disabled + $track": {
      backgroundColor: "green",
      opacity: 0.5
    }
  },
  track: {},
  disabled: {}
})(MuiSwitch);

export default function Switches() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch disabled inputProps={{ "aria-label": "disabled checkbox" }} />
      <Switch
        disabled
        checked
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Switch disabled style]

---

Below is a v5 example leveraging `styled`:

```
import React from "react";
import MuiSwitch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { switchClasses } from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const Switch = styled(MuiSwitch)(`
  & .${switchClasses.switchBase}.${switchClasses.disabled} {
    color: yellow
  }
  & .${switchClasses.switchBase}.${switchClasses.disabled} + .${switchClasses.track} {
      background-color: green;
      opacity: 0.5
  }
`);

export default function Switches() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Switch disabled inputProps={{ "aria-label": "disabled checkbox" }} />
      <Switch
        disabled
        checked
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Switch disabled style]

Comment: Yeah, that insight about needing to have a "disabled: {}" was key to making things work. Thanks for that. In order to get what I needed, I had to nest the rule for disabled hierarchically under the rule for checked and then it worked. Thanks for the help Ryan.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because when `Switch` is disabled, css loads `.MuiSwitch-colorSecondary.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track`. So you have to override this class if you want to change backgroudColor when `Switch` is disabled.

So your Switch becomes:

```
const MySwitch = withStyles({
    switchBase: {
        color: "orange",
        opacity: 0.8,
        "&$checked": {
            color: "orange",
            opacity: 1
        },
        "&$checked + $track": {
            backgroundColor: "black",
            opacity: 1
        },
        "&.MuiSwitch-colorSecondary.Mui-disabled + .MuiSwitch-track": {
            backgroundColor: "black"
        }
    },
    checked: {},
    track: {}
})(Switch);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-cc7kh?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example.

The result is:

[image]

The first one is disabled, the second is enable.

Comment: I tried the code listed here and it didn't work, but the code that is in codesandbox, which is a little different, did end up working. There was helpful stuff in there. Thanks Giovanni.

Comment: @Brian I'm sorry. If you could replicate your problem in a codesandbox I could take a look on this. Let me know.

Comment: Check out the post I just added. It did end up working like that. I think I'm all set for now. Thanks again for the help!